# MongoDB: find element by array element

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am having the following issue. Generally I have a collection holding objects with the following structure:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("4f941bb2e4b06c6af7f80a0d"),
    fooId: ObjectId("4f941bb2e4b06c6af7e50aff"), 
    barsIds: [ObjectId("4f941bb2f5606c6af7f80ff5"), ObjectId("4f941bbc3fb06c6af7f80ccf")]
}
```

What is the query to find all elements in the collection that contain a given id in the barsIds property ?

Is it something like:

```
db.collectionName.find({"barsIds" : [ { "$oid" : "5300c6ba4a5ce5614bcd5d9a"}]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what you are looking for:

```
db.collectionName.find({"barsIds" : ObjectId("4f941bb2f5606c6af7f80ff5") })
```

This query looks for documents whose `barsIds` elements are given object id. Or if `barsIds` is an array, this query looks for docs whose `barsIds` elements contain given object id.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this

```
db.collectionName.find({:barsIds => {"$in" => BSON::ObjectId("5300c6ba4a5ce5614bcd5d9a")}})
```